# getting error with _set in Django Query-Set, object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield, django-errors

I use **_set** to make `ManyToMany` relationship between *customer* and *Service* but endup having **Error:**

**AttributeError at /customer/1/** 
**'carOwner' object has no attribute 'serviceOrderX_get'**

*Is there anyone who want to help me..*

**models.py**

```
...

class carOwner(models.Model):
    name_X = models.CharField( max_length=150, null=True)
    email_X = models.CharField( max_length=150, null=True)
    phoneNo_X =models.CharField( max_length=150, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_X

class serviceOrderX(models.Model):
    CATEGORES = (...)
    carName_X = models.CharField( max_length=150, null=True)
    carNO_X = models.CharField( max_length=150, null=True)
    carOwner_X = models.ManyToManyField(carOwner)
    catagores_X = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,choices=CATEGORES)
    price_X = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    service_X = models.ManyToManyField(orderService)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.carName_X} , {self.carNO_X}')
```

**views.py**

```
...

def CustomerX(request , pk):
    customersX = carOwner.objects.get(id=pk)
    cuter = customersX.serviceOrderX_set.all()

    contX = {
        'customer' : cuter , 
    }
    return render(request, 'customer.html' , contX)
```

Comment: `serviceorderx_get`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a typo in your code. It should be `set` instead of `get`  -> `customersX.serviceOrderX_set.all()`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

You can also set a `related_name` on your ManyToManyField like `service_orders` so that you can do `customersX.service_orders.all()`

Btw. just a hint, using camel case for your fields in python is not a good style.
Just do `car_owner_x` and for your class names use eg `ServiceOrderX`

See: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relate field, the first argument you should add is name of model you want to relate. In your case you can fix this

```
class serviceOrderX(models.Model):
    # change here
    service_X = models.ManyToManyField(carOwner)
```

read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/